# How I can select specific record from a GROUP BY without over-load the process?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case, query-optimization

I have n record from the table EAT OR DRINK that correspond to some events that can have duplicate IDs.

For every event, I need to group by ID and make in evidence always things that we can eat (GROUP 1) instead things that we can drink (GROUP 2). In synthesis, I will put GROUP 2 string only if there are not string of GROUP 1.

```
GROUP 1: ('PIZZA',POTATO','EGGS','STRAWBERRY') 
GROUP 2: ('COCA COLA','ORANGE JUICE','BITTER','TEA')
```

when I GROUP BY ID, strings of the GROUP 1 win ALWAYS between string of GROUP 2. Win it means that I need always to take in a group a string of the GROUP 1 instead of the GROUP 2 but if there's no GROUP 1 string in a group I need to take GROUP 2 string.

After the group by, I chose to use the MAX function and a case when inside putting some conditions.

I did this query and it works, but when I use this in another view the performance are very low. It is strange because when i Run this alone, it works in 4 seconds but inside another view seems very very bad and Slowly and I cannot use in production:

```
SELECT 
    a.NETWORKID,
    CASE WHEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] IS NOT NULL THEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] ELSE b.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] END AS [MOTIVO_DESCRIZIONE]
FROM
    (SELECT
         a.NETWORKID,
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'PIZZA' or a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'POTATO' or a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'EGGS' or a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'STRAWBERRY' THEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] ELSE NULL END) AS [MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE]
     FROM dbo.v_eventi a
     GROUP BY a.NETWORKID, a.[DDT NUMERO]) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
         a.NETWORKID,
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'COCA COLA' or a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'ORANGE JUICE' or a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'BITTER' or a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] = 'TEA'  THEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] ELSE NULL END) AS [MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE]
     FROM dbo.v_eventi a
     GROUP BY a.NETWORKID, a.[DDT NUMERO]) b ON a.NETWORKID = b.NETWORKID
```

Could someone help me and have better ideas to make faster this query?
or do I need to use a stored procedure that fills a table every day with this transformations?

Thanks to all the kind community in advance.

Comment: Your code looks like SQL Server (MS SQL) one. And it is not compatible with MySQL...

Comment: is DDT Numero different between the same networkid?

Comment: @siggemannen yes, could be happen that DDT numero and Network id are same so i need to group by also that column

Comment: @Akina thanks, modified but have you any useful answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several opportunities for improvement.

1. In the final select, the `CASE` statement used to select between the food or the drink can be replaced with a `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` function. The code would then become `ISNULL(a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE], b.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE]) AS [MOTIVO_DESCRIZIONE]`.
2. The multiple comparisons in each subselect can be replaced with an `IN (...)` condition. The code would then become `WHEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] IN ('PIZZA', 'POTATO', 'EGGS', 'STRAWBERRY')` and similar for the drink subselect.
3. (Very minor) In your *conditional aggregation* `CASE` expressions, the `ELSE NULL` part can be dropped, as that is the default behavior when no explicit `ELSE` is present.
4. I see no reason why the two subselects cannot be combined, with both the food and drink calculations performed and combined into a single select. Using  `ISNULL()` in that final select avoids duplicate expressions, that might have been an issue with the original `CASE` expression use.

The result would be something like:

```
SELECT
    a.NETWORKID,
    -- a.[DDT NUMERO],
    ISNULL(
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] IN ('PIZZA', 'POTATO', 'EGGS', 'STRAWBERRY')
            THEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE]
            END),
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE] IN ('COCA COLA', 'ORANGE JUICE', 'BITTER', 'TEA')
            THEN a.[MOTIVO DESCRIZIONE]
            END)
    ) AS [MOTIVO_DESCRIZIONE]
FROM dbo.v_eventi a
GROUP BY a.NETWORKID, a.[DDT NUMERO]
```